# Google+ API. Sharing interactive posts error. Claimed origin not in whitelist

Tags: google-plus

I do everything as stated on this page [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive) however, the window appears for a split second, and then an error in the console "Claimed origin not in whitelist: (mySiteLink)"

Comment: Can you add some more context as to what you are trying to do?  Also, check that your website is listed as an authorized origin in the Google Developers Console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your web origin in the Google API Console should only include http:// or https:// and then the host name. Make sure you don't have / in the end.
The web origin is under the OAuth 2.0 Client ID section in the Console.

Answer (score 1):

I remove the '/' at the end of "Javascript Origins" url and solve.
Example:
Original that error URL: http://www.example.com/

Changed to URL: http://www.example.com

Problem solved.